# How can i update QMenu and sub menu title text ‘s dynamically

Tags: c++, qmenu

i have QMenu that holds sub menu 
i like to be able to update each menu title string dynamccly for example 
i have this menu

```
[main menu ] Groups 2
       [sub menu]  group_X 3
       [sub menu]  group_Y 1
```

i like to be able to change only the numbers part of the string in each menu entry from my application 
which approach should i peek ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [title](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmenu.html#title-prop)

```
menu -> setTitle (tr ("Number %1") .arg (123));
```

Comment: how can i update dynamically the arg method without rewriting the title over and over again

Comment: You store the schematic string "Number %1" somewhere and regenerate the final string with `arg(n)` each time you need to update. Yes this will replace the whole string. No you should not worry about it.